# Convert Tuple IEnumerable to List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to convert Tuple `IEnumerable` to a `List<string>`. For example, if there is

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Type>> GetWord(String formula)
```

how can I pass the enumerable directly into the constructor of a new `List<string>`???

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear but to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<V>` you can use Linq's `Select` and `ToList` methods.

Answer (score 7):

`Select` is probably what you want

```
var list = new List<string>(GetWord.Select(x => x.Item1));
```

Comment: While this answer is exactly what OP asks for (except you forgot that `GetWord` is a method), I do consider Fabio's answer of `.ToList()` to be more idiomatic in this case.

Comment: @Flater i think the only reason it is done this way, because OP asked explicitly "how can I pass the enumerable directly into the constructor of a new List<string>"

Answer (score 2):

With `Select` extension method you can convert enumerable of Tuple to the enumerable of string.
And then you can create a `List<string>` without explicitly passing enumerable to the `List` constructor, but by using `ToList` extension method.

```
var list = GetWord(formula).Select(t => t.Item1).ToList();
```